# How to organize source files of Java program?

Tags: java, resources, jar, exe, project-organization

I've created small program in `Java`. It uses Java classes, some images and generates some other resources (`.php` files, images, stylesheets etc).

I'm compiling sources as `.jar` and creating an `.exe` program, which should use my `.jar` and other resources.

What is the best practice to organize all sources of my Java program?

Comment: a common way to organize your java classes is to spread them among packages(following the hierarchy you want), while you can create separate folders (images, css, scripts) to hold your images and other stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will recommend the below maven structure as the [standard convention](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) even if you are not using maven.

```
src/main/java   Application/Library sources
src/main/resources  Application/Library resources
src/main/filters    Resource filter files
src/main/assembly   Assembly descriptors
src/main/config Configuration files
src/main/scripts    Application/Library scripts
src/main/webapp Web application sources
src/test/java   Test sources
src/test/resources  Test resources
src/test/filters    Test resource filter files
src/site    Site
LICENSE.txt Project's license
NOTICE.txt  Notices and attributions required by libraries that the project depends on
README.txt  Project's readme
```

Comment: +1 i swear was thinking about maven too :D, good to see your answer.

Comment: I am using Maven, so your answer perfectly suits me. Thanks!

Comment: But I don't understand what for is `src/site`. Static website templates?

Comment: Look here http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-site.html to understand what goes into "site"