# Ant - How to exclude Java test files?

Tags: java, ant

I want to copy Java code from a source folder to a target folder and compile it, but need to exclude some testing code. How can I only copy the non-test code? For example, I want to include `bb/app/lite2` and exclude `bb/app/test1`, `bb/app/cg`,...

I know I can use the exclude element, but I don't want to write so many exclude patterns. So can I just use:

`<exclude name="bb/app/**">` and then use `<include name="bb/app/lite2">`?

Answer (score 5):

Given the directory structure mentioned in your question, it sounds like all of your non-test code is in the directory `bb/app/lite2`. In that case, you could write the `<copy>` task as follows as long as `bb/app/lite2` appears below the specified source directory:

```
<property name="source.dir" location="${basedir}/src" />
<property name="target.dir" location="${basedir}/target" />

<copy todir="${target.dir}" overwrite="true">
  <fileset dir="${source.dir}" includes="bb/app/lite2/**/*.java" />
</copy>
```

However, adopting a naming convention for your test files such as `<ClassName>Test.java` makes it possible to write includes/excludes patterns as follows.

### Copy all sources excluding tests

```
<property name="source.dir" location="${basedir}/src" />
<property name="target.dir" location="${basedir}/target" />

<copy todir="${target.dir}" overwrite="true">
  <fileset dir="${source.dir}" 
      includes="**/*.java" excludes="**/*Test.java" />
</copy>
```

The [`<javac>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) Ant task supports `includes` and `excludes` attributes, so rather than copy source files to a new directory, you can select the non-test files directly.

### Use `<javac>` Ant task `includes` and `excludes` attributes

```
<property name="source.dir" location="${basedir}/src" />
<property name="classes.dir" location="${basedir}/build/classes" />

<javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
    includes="**/*.java" excludes="**/*Test.java"
    classpathref="my.classpath" debug="on" deprecation="on" />
```

As [David W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368630/david-w) mentioned in his comment, another convention (that may used in conjunction with a file naming convention) is to place test code in a separate directory. For example,

- `src/java`
- `test/src/java`

Or following the maven convention:

- `src/main/java`
- `src/test/java`

Then compiling your non-test sources is simple since you do not have to specify includes/excludes patterns:

```
<property name="source.dir" location="${basedir}/src/java" />
<property name="classes.dir" location="${basedir}/build/classes" />

<javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"
    classpathref="my.classpath" debug="on" deprecation="on" />
```

#### Related stackoverflow questions

- [How to organize source files of Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11926334/1164465)
- [Organization of JUnit tests in projects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183780/1164465)

Comment: Actually, a better way of doing this is to follow Maven conventions (even if you're not using Maven) and put your test code and your regular code in separate directories. In Maven, one is in `src/main/java` while the other is in `src/test/java` (I'll leave it to the reader to figure out which is which). You can also put resources that are required in jars, but are not java files into `src/main/resources`. Makes it much easier to do your work if it isn't all in a single directory. Otherwise, use `<include name="..."/>` and `<exclude name="..."/>` subtasks for the `<fileset/>` command.